# Pillow: Cannot Convert 'P' to 'RGB'

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I'm trying to convert all image files within a folder to jpg using Pillow.

I'm new to pillow so I'm not 100% on my grasp of the concepts.

Here are the functions I'm using:

```
def convert_jpg(file, folder = 'flag_images/', delete = False):
    filepath = folder + file
    print(file)
    img = Image.open(filepath, mode = 'r')
    if delete:
        img.save(folder + 'backup/' + file)
        os.remove(filepath)
    if img.mode != 'RGB':
        img.convert('RBG')
    filepath = filepath[0:-3] + 'jpg'
    img.save(filepath)

def convert_all(folder = 'flag_images/'):
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + '/flag_images'):
        if filename[-3:] != 'jpg':
            convert_jpg(file = filename, folder = folder, delete = True)
```

When running convert_all, I get the following error when I get to a file with mode 'P':

```
ValueError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in convert(self, mode, matrix, dither, palette, colors)
   1025         try:
-> 1026             im = self.im.convert(mode, dither)
   1027         except ValueError:

ValueError: conversion not supported
```

How can I successfully convert the mode to RGB, so that I can save as a jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo and a usage error. You'd need to change this:

```
img.convert('RBG')
```

to this:

```
img = img.convert('RGB')
```

That said, it shouldn't be necessary at all, since JPEG is necessarily not `P` mode.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with this edit. I'm also not sure what you mean by "shouldn't be necessary". I need to convert these png files to jpg, and the conversation fails if it's not in RGB mode. How do I convert a P mode to RGB?

Comment: Never mind- I see the typo now. Leaving the comment up to be properly shamed.